# Do this tag and proposal match?

Tags: discussion, tags

I had recently noticed that this SE site have a tag 'script'. I had proposed a SE site in area 51 named ['S' for script'](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101170/s-for-script). Do this tag and and proposal match? please help if you know something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe that is a match.

[script](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) refers to, as T.E.D. said, "the actual set of glyphs a language's writing system uses".

The phrase ["ancient scripts and scrolls"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ancient+scripts+and+scrolls+%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), as you can see in the linked google results, is most often used to refer to script in the sense of an ancient manuscript, or document.

I don't believe there is a match here. Now, T.E.D. is being cautious because we don't have a lot of information on the proposal, and there is a possibility I am wrong. I'm just telling you what I believe given the current information.

Comment: That said, T.E.D.'s concerns with that proposal still apply. It looks like it would be a subset of this site's subject area, which means it probably won't do well.

Answer (score 1):

Like most words in English, "script" has several meanings. One of those meanings, in fact I'd say the **predominant** meaning among us computer software types, is the actual set of glyphs a language's [writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing_system) uses. For example, must English writers use the [Latin Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script). That seems to be mostly the sense in which our users are using [script](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script).

Its a very useful term, because not every writing system uses an "Alphabet". Chinese most notably is a logogram-based system. The word "script" covers both.

Looking through what we have for that tag, it indeed mostly seems to be used for questions about the historical mechanics of writing. For example questions about glyphs used for specific old languages. Only one of the six is actually a question about the meaning of the information in an old work. Such a question would certainly be on-topic here though.

---

Now looking through your proposal, I'm not sure how much of a match you'd call that. It seems to me you are shooting for questions about interpreting the information in old documents, but to me its very confusing. The next two most common meanings of the word "script" I'm familiar with are (in order)

1. The ordered set of lines and direction used to plan out a play, TV show, movie, or similar performance work.
2. An abbreviation for manuscript. Typically this means an unedited draft of a written work. However, sometimes [Manuscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuscript) is used to mean a hand-written work.

If someone was talking specifically about old writings, I'd expect to see the term "ancient manuscript". If I see "script", an ancient manuscript would be pretty low on my mental rolodex of things the writer could be referring to.

---

As a third meta-criticism:

I'm not saying this is what you are doing, (because frankly I don't understand your proposed domain right now), but I'd advise anyone creating a proposal that's essentially a proper subset of this stack to be realistic about what you are getting into.

We average about 5 questions a day here. That's not horrible, but its still "beta" level. You shouldn't expect to get more than that with a subset of our domain, and will likely get a fair bit less. For example, [HSM](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65204/history-of-science-and-mathematics) and [Mythology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology) both are running at less than one question a day now.

A smarter idea would be to wait until this stack is out of beta, and has additional traffic heavy enough to justify splitting off part of its domain into another healthy stack.

Comment: ...but I thought Fax machines were a stupid idea first time I saw one in the '80, so what do I know?

Comment: Fax machines are still a stupid idea.

Comment: well i am not getting any specific answer in order to this question. i am clearly asking that matchs or not! that's it

Comment: @microbuster T.E.D. said: "Now looking through your proposal, I'm not sure how much of a match you'd call that." In other words, your answer is "Probably not".

Comment: @called2voyage - Well, no. The answer is "someone who understands the proposal would have to judge that". I honestly wasn't trying to be diplomatic there. I don't understand the scope of the proposal. So what I'm trying to do here is explain what our tag means in the hope than someone who **does** understand the proposal can easily answer the question.

Comment: @T.E.D. In that case, I'll post my own answer.

Comment: @T.E.D. well thanks! the information you had given says that its not a match.